# How can I solve this nonlinear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$m \cdot y''+k \cdot y + u \cdot sign(y') = 0 $$

Does this have an analytic solution? If not, how do you know?

I've tried to use the Laplace transform, but I can't figure out how to deal with the sign function of the derivative.

Also, since it's nonlinear, I can't use any of those techniques.

Comment: What is $u$ ?  ...

Comment: k, u, and m are constants

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1 = y$ and $z_2 = y'$, so $z_1' = z_2$ and $z_2' = -kz_1-u\text{sign}(z_2)$. Then the equation can be written as $\mathbf z' = F(\mathbf z)$. This is a first order nonlinear equation. Since $F$ is continuously differentiable for $\mathbf z$ in the upper or lower half planes, the usual existence and uniqueness theorems guarantee that initial conditions in either of those spaces will have unique solutions for some region surrounding it, not passing the $z_1$-axis, which will coincide with the solutions for the linear equations with $\text{sign}(z_2) = \pm z_2$ respectively. Orbits in the upper half plane will be upper half ellipses with center $(-\frac{u}{k},0)$, and orbits in the lower half plane will be lower half ellipses with center $(\frac{u}{k},0)$. These orbits are analytic in their respective half planes, but the connections on the $z_1$-axis have discontinuous second derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

$$m \cdot y''+k \cdot y + u \cdot \text{sign}(y') = 0 $$

In the domain where $y'>0\qquad \begin{cases}
m \cdot y''+k \cdot y + u = 0\quad\text{which general solution is :}\\
y(t)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)-\frac{u}{k}\\
y'(t)=-c_1\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t) 
\end{cases}$

In the domain where $y'<0\qquad \begin{cases}
m \cdot y''+k \cdot y - u = 0\quad\text{which general solution is :}\\
y(t)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+\frac{u}{k}\\
y'(t)= -c_1\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t) osed form
\end{cases}$

The general solution can be written on close form :
$$y(t)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)-\frac{u}{k} \text{sign}\left(-c_1\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t)+c_2\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\:t) \right)$$

The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be determined according to some boundary conditions. Since no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question, no further calculus is possible.